# My DateTime.TryParseExact() logic rejecting valid formats

Tags: datetime, c#-4.0

I'm parsing a DateTime value in an C# Winform Application and the date string keeps getting rejected by the DateTime.TryParseExact() method even though it clearly matches one of the supplied format strings.

```
    DateTime tmpDateTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        return DateTime.TryParseExact("Jan 13 2014  1:11PM", "MMM dd yyyy HH:mmtt",            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tmpDateTime);
```

Comment: I think you have an extra space between your year and time in the first param. Also, `h:mmtt` is what you'd want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're very close. Try this:

```
return DateTime.TryParseExact("Jan 13 2014 1:11PM", "MMM dd yyyy h:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tmpDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

My two thoughts are

1. Does the month need to be capitalized
2. Does there need to be two digits for the HH slot?  Try changing 1 to 01

Also I'm not sure if it's relevant but there is an extra space between the date and time in your example, for consistency sake you should probably remove it.

Comment: to be honest don't have control over the formatting I read in the date time value from a server in the format I have provided above can't get it to work.

Comment: yes, I know it comes from the server like that I don't have access to the source code, but maybe u on to something will try to parse it first extract the time, and date, then the apply the extra 0 if needed, then try to parse the date and time, then let u know